# How to autowire this dependency in spring at the time of PostConstruct

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-inversion

I have the below code inside the `@PostConstruct` block in a spring managed code.

```
class A {

    private BoogleFeature boogle;

    @PostConstruct
        public void createBoggleClient() {
                SDKPersona.SDKPersonaBuilder sdkBuilder =
                        new AppIdentifier.SDKPersonaBuilder()
                                .setRegistryId(config.getRegistryId())
                                .setRegistrySecret(config.getRegistrySecret())
        
                boggle = new BoggleFeature(sdkBuilder.build());
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want to not do a `boggle = new BoggleFeature(sdkBuilder.build());` and make it as bean and inject it as a deopendency . How can i achieve that.

Answer (score 3):

did you try below, you can put below code in come configuration class

```
    @Bean(name="boggleFeature")
    public BoggleFeature createBoggleClient() {
        SDKPersona.SDKPersonaBuilder sdkBuilder =
            new AppIdentifier.SDKPersonaBuilder()
                .setRegistryId(config.getRegistryId())
                .setRegistrySecret(config.getRegistrySecret())
    
        return new BoggleFeature(sdkBuilder.build());
    }
```

Then you can use with autowired any where

```
 @Autowired
    private BoogleFeature boogle
```

Comment: The idea is to get rid of the new keyword and inject it as a dependency , right

Comment: You should mention that `@Bean` part should go into `@Configuration` class. In general you should explain how your code solves problem

Comment: @station  you will have do it once and subsequently you can use if anywhere as dependency

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GenericApplicationContext` to register the bean dynamically during  `@PostConstruct` this way :

```
@Component
public class BoogleFactory {

  @Autowired
  private GenericApplicationContext context;

  @PostConstruct
  public void createBoggleClient() {
    //build the sdk
    String sdk = "Boogle SDK";

    //then register the bean in spring context with constructor args
    context.registerBean(BoogleFeature.class,sdk);
  }

}
```

The bean to register dynamically:

```
public class BoogleFeature {

  private String sdk;

  public BoogleFeature(String sdk) {
    this.sdk = sdk;
  }

  public String doBoogle() {
    return "Boogling with " + sdk;
  }
}
```

You can then use, Anywhere in your app:

```
@Component
class AClassUsingBoogleFeature {
   @Autowired
   BoogleFeature boogleFeature; //<-- this will have the sdk instantiated already
}
```

The following test proves that, after spring context initialization,
(which will initialize `BooglerFactory` then call the `@Postcontruct` method BTW),
you can use `Boogler` with `@Autowired` anywhere.

```
@SpringBootTest
public class BooglerTest {

  @Autowired
  BoogleFeature boogleFeature;

  @Test
  void boogleFeature_ShouldBeInstantiated() {
    assert "Boogling with Boogle SDK".equals(boogleFeature.doBoogle());
  }

}
```

`registerBean` has more powerful options, [check it out here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/GenericApplicationContext.html#registerBean-java.lang.Class-org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionCustomizer...-).

Comment: Not able to undetsand how will this remove my `new` keyword . If you can show an example that will really help

Comment: @station I have updated my answer to show: 1/ How you register the bean WITH CONSTRUCTOR ARGS --- 2/ How to use the bean anywhere else --- 3/ the test demonstrates it works.

Comment: Tried this but to no avail, the bean doesnt get registered : (

Comment: I've tested it and it works. I'm using Spring boot 2.4.3 . Double check every step please.